# Login Manager Facebook Android SDK

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin

This facebook Android SDK is giving me some problems...

I'm working on a Xamarin forms application, and for the Android part I am using Facebook Android SDK for my facebook connections.

So my connection is working with this code :

```
var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback(mCallBackManager, this);
        LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithPublishPermissions(activity, ExtendedWritePermissions );
        LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(activity, ExtendedReadPermissions);
```

But when I try to look if the user is logged to facebook in my app, the result is always null :

```
if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null && Profile.CurrentProfile != null)
        {
            //The user is log in through facebook
            return true;
        }

        //The user is not log in through facebook

        return false;
```

The two variables used in the if are always null.

I initialize the SDK on my MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "Let's Go Out", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Locale | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(this.ApplicationContext);

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        App.ScreenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }
}
```